# How to nest xsl:for-each select

Tags: html

I am trying to do something very similar to what was asked back in 2009 -.  The difference is that I want to go one more level deeper.  I don't have problems getting the ID, poNumber, etc information.  My problem is being able to get the Accounting information to the HTML form.  Any suggestions on how I need to update my xslt stylesheet?  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank You!

```
xml:
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xmlString><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resultSet xmlns="">
    <Record>
        <ID>27184882</ID>
        <poNumber>EP40158</poNumber>
        <eventDate>Tue, 19 Nov, 2013</eventDate>
        <totalCost>400</totalCost>
      <LineItems>
            <Item>1</Item>
            <Part_Number>part456</Part_Number>
            <Unit>EA</Unit>
            <Quantity>20</Quantity>
            <Description>3rd line</Description>
            <AdditionalInfo>
                <FieldName>Print Job Title or Description</FieldName>
                <FieldValue>Test Print Test Print </FieldValue>
            </AdditionalInfo>
            <AdditionalInfo>
                <FieldName>SDN Phone</FieldName>
                <FieldValue>214-792-4312</FieldValue>
            </AdditionalInfo>
            <Accounting>
                <splitQuantity>20</splitQuantity>
                <costCenter>21000</costCenter>
                <genLedger>5600680</genLedger>
            </Accounting>
        </LineItems>
        <LineItems>
            <Item>2</Item>
            <Part_Number>part456</Part_Number>
            <Unit>EA</Unit>
            <Quantity>400</Quantity>
           <requisitionRequester>e61140</requisitionRequester>
            <AdditionalInfo>
                <FieldName>Print Job Title or Description</FieldName>
                <FieldValue>Line 2 Print Test</FieldValue>
            </AdditionalInfo>
            <Accounting>
                <splitQuantity>20</splitQuantity>
                <costCenter>21000</costCenter>
                <genLedger>5600680</genLedger>
            </Accounting>
        </LineItems>
        <LineItems>
            <Item>3</Item>
            <Part_Number>part567</Part_Number>
            <Unit>EA</Unit>
            <Quantity>35</Quantity>
            <Description>testing</Description>
            <AdditionalInfo>
                <FieldName>Print Job Title or Description</FieldName>
                <FieldValue>Testing</FieldValue>
            </AdditionalInfo>
            <AdditionalInfo>
                <FieldName>SDN Phone</FieldName>
                <FieldValue>214-792-4312</FieldValue>
            </AdditionalInfo>
            <Accounting>
                <splitQuantity>20</splitQuantity>
                <costCenter>21000</costCenter>
                <genLedger>5600680</genLedger>
            </Accounting>
        </LineItems>
    </Record>
</resultSet>
</xmlString>
```

HTML Output desired:

```
Item Part Number Unit Quantity Description Need By Unit Price Extended Amount 
1 part456 EA 20 3rd line Wed, 01 Jan, 2014 10 200 
Additional Information 
Field Name Field Value 
Print Job Title or Description Test Print Test Print  
Field Name Field Value 
SDN Phone 214-792-4312 
Item Part Number Unit Quantity Description Need By Unit Price Extended Amount 
2 part456 EA 400 4th line Sun, 12 Jan, 2014 10 4000 
Additional Information 
Field Name Field Value 
Print Job Title or Description Line 2 Print Test 
Item Part Number Unit Quantity Description Need By Unit Price Extended Amount 
3 part567 EA 35 testing Sat, 11 Jan, 2014 1166.7 3500 
Additional Information 
Field Name Field Value 
Print Job Title or Description Testing 
Field Name Field Value 
SDN Phone 214-792-4312
```

here is the xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Order <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/poNumber"></xsl:value-of></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <font face="Arial Helvetica" size = "1">
    <p>
        <h2>Order No. <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/poNumber"/> </h2>
        Version Number: <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/Version"/><br/>
        Internal Version: false<br/>
        Issued on  <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/eventDate"/><br/>
        Created on  <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/eventDate"/><br/><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <table border="0" width="95%%">
        <tr valign="top">
            <td colspan="4">
                <font size="2">
                    <b>Supplier:</b><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/supplierName"/><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/supplierStreet"/><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/supplierCity"/>, <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/supplierState"/>   
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/supplierZipcode"/><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/supplierCountry"/><br/>
                    Phone: 1 <br/>
                    Fax: 1 <br/>
                    Contact: <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/supplierContact"/><br/>
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
    <p>
        <table border="0" width="95%%">
        <tr valign="top">
            <td colspan="4">
                <font size="2">
                    <b>Bill To:</b><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/billtoName"/><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/billtoStreet"/><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/billtoCity"/>, <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/billtoState"/>  <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/billtoZipcode"/><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/billtoCountry"/><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/billtoPhone"/><br/>
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
    <p>
        <table border="0" width="95%%">
        <tr valign="top">
            <td colspan="4">
                <font size="2">
                    <b>Ship To:</b><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/shiptoName"/><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/shiptoStreet"/><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/shiptoCity"/>, <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/billtoState"/>    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/shiptoZipcode"/><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/shiptoCountry"/><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/shiptoPhone"/><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <b>Deliver To: </b>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/deliverTo"/><br/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/resultSet/Record/shippingAddress"/><br/>
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
    <p>
        <table border="0" width="95%%">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td>
                    <font size="2">
                        <b>Additional Information: </b>
                        <p>
                        Terms and Conditions: This purchase subject to the attached Southwest Airlines Terms and Conditions.
                        </p>
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p>
        <table border="1" width="95%%">
        <xsl:for-each select="/resultSet/Record/LineItems">
            <tr valign="top">
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Part Number</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Need By</th>
                <th>Unit Price</th>
                <th>Extended Amount</th>
            </tr>
                <td><xsl:apply-templates select="Item"/></td>
                <td><xsl:apply-templates select="Part_Number"/></td>
                <td><xsl:apply-templates select="Unit"/></td>
                <td><xsl:apply-templates select="Quantity"/></td>
                <td><xsl:apply-templates select="Description"/></td>
                <td><xsl:apply-templates select="Need_By"/></td>
                <td><xsl:apply-templates select="Unit_Price"/></td>
                <td><xsl:apply-templates select="Extended_Amount"/></td>
            <tr valign="top">
                <th>Additional Information</th>
            </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="./AdditionalInfo">
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <th>Field Name</th>
                        <th>Field Value</th>
                    </tr>
                        <td><xsl:apply-templates select="FieldName"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:apply-templates select="FieldValue"/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./LineItems/Accounting">
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <td></td>
                            <td colspan="8"> <font size="2">
                                Requester: <xsl:apply-templates select="requisitionRequester"/><br/>
                                PR No.: <xsl:apply-templates select="requisitionID"/><br/>
                            </font></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </p>
    </font> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Your current XSLT template is missing .... can you show us?

Comment: Added the XSLT template to the posting of question

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you at all.  This for-each statement: <xsl:for-each select="./LineItems/Accounting"> returns nothing, since you are in the other for-each statement which is enumerating /resultSet/Record/LineItems.  I believe you should change it to <xsl:for-each select="./Accounting"> and as for this:

Requester: <xsl:apply-templates select="requisitionRequester"/><br/>
PR No.: <xsl:apply-templates select="requisitionID"/><br/>

I don't see anything in your XML which matches this.